# Shortcode of a function

Tags: functions, shortcode, html

I got this function and i want to make the contents divs of "foreach" as return. How can i do that?

```
<?php 
    $args = array( 'numberposts' => 6, 'post_status'=>"publish",'post_type'=>"post",'orderby'=>"post_date");
    $postslist = get_posts( $args );

    foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
       <div class="events">
             <p><strong><?php the_date(); ?></strong></p>
           <p><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p> 
      </div>
<?php endforeach; ?> 

/// Top Section Block
add_shortcode('top_section_block', 'shortcode_top_section_block');

    function shortcode_top_section_block($atts) {
        extract(shortcode_atts(
            array(
                'content' => '',

            ), $atts));

            return ' ';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a string instead of directly outputting the contents.

```
$str = '';
foreach ($postslist as $post) : setup_postdata($post); 
  $str .= '<div class="events">';
    $str .= '<p><strong>'.get_the_date().'</strong></p>';
    $str .= '<p><a href="'.get_permalink().'" title="'.esc_attr(get_the_title()).'">'.get_the_title().'</a></p>';
  $str .= '</div>';
endforeach;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-get-clean.php) to grab the output as a string.

```
ob_start();
// do your foreach bits here
$output = ob_get_clean();

return $output;
```

Comment: nice, but how will be my code? Where i put the rest?

Comment: My code goes in your shortcode function. See the bit that says, `// do your foreach bits here` ? That's where your foreach code goes.